# Is there a way to set object keys from array value in one line

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

say I have an array like this:

```
const myArray = ['HP', 'QP', 'PS'];
```

And I'd like to have an object whose keys are `myArray`'s values like

```
{ HP: 0, QP: 0, PS: 0 }
```

Is there a way to do the following in one line:

```
const myObj = {};
myArray.forEach(item => myObj[item] = 0);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try using `reduce`:

```js
const myArray = ['HP', 'QP', 'PS'];
const myObj = myArray.reduce((a, key) => Object.assign(a, { [key]: 0 }), {});
console.log(myObj);
```

In newer environments, you can also use `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
const myArray = ['HP', 'QP', 'PS'];
const myObj = Object.fromEntries(myArray.map(key => [key, 0]));
console.log(myObj);
```

Answer (score 6):

You could spread ([spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)) mapped objects into one object with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```js
var keys = ['HP', 'QP', 'PS'],
    object = Object.assign(...keys.map(key => ({ [key]: 0 })));
    
console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 2):

A one liner:

```js
console.log(
  ['HP', 'QP', 'PS']
    .map( v => ({[v]: 0}) )
    .reduce( (p, n) => ({...p, ...n}), {} )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
console.log(['HP', 'QP', 'PS'] .reduce( (p, n) => ({...p, [n] :0 }), {} ));
```